# Using BoringSSL With Vertx (ALPN)

Tags: java, maven, netty, vert.x

I am trying to use BoringSSL with Vertx so that I can use ALPN. I am running vertx 3.7.1 and have included the following in my pom.xml-

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.23.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run my application I get the following message- "ALPN not available for JDK SSL/TLS engine". If I add `<scope>runtime</scope>` or `<scrope>compile</scope>` to the dependency, I will not get this message when I run the application through my IDE.

However, when I build a jar with any of the scopes (or no scope defined) the resulting jar does not contain the boringssl piece. More specifically, there is an `io.netty` package, but the `io.netty.internal.tcnative` is missing.

How can I include this package in the final jar I'm building?

Comment: How do you package your application? As a fat jar?